# How can I have 2nd div row ignore parent div's width

Tags: css

I've three child div and wanted that middle div to ignore width of parent div and take full screen width (yet it needs to maintain its position below first div)

Comment: It is easier to help if you include some code.

Comment: Got it solved see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sachingpta/3qu3m466/), thanks.

Comment: @SachinGupta You'd better delete that question then. Sam was right that your question was too vague: there was many ways to solve what was asked, but most of them didn't fit your real (unwritten) requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by using `position: absolute` tag. See JSfiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/sachingpta/3qu3m466/. Sample code

`

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.parent{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: grey;    
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.child1{
    background-color: red;
}
.child2{
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
.child3{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can define the middle child width a width defined in `vw`:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
}
.child {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
.overflower {
  width: 100vw;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class=parent>
  <div class=child>child</div>
  <div class=overflower>overflows</div>
  <div class=child>child</div>
</div>
```